# why nothing happens when I execute commands on the discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

i got an problem with this code here... i am starting with programming and this discord bot is my first bigger project and i want to lern it

```
# bot.py
import os
import random
import discord
import time
import sys
import logging

from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# importing your Discord Token
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

# create bot var and prefix
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='h!')

logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='discord.log', encoding = 'utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

def restart_bot():
    python = sys.executable()
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    channel = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_channels(), name='testl')
    await channel.send("Ich bin wieder da")

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send('Du hast die benötigten Rechte nicht!')

@bot.command(name='69', help='Just nice!')
async def six_nine(ctx):
    await ctx.send('nice!')

@bot.command(name='roll-dice', help='(würfel, augen) simuliert einen würfel')
async def roll_dice(ctx, number_of_dices, number_of_sides):
    dice = [
        str(random.choice(range(1, number_of_sides)))
        for _ in range(number_of_dices)
    ]
    await ctx.send(', '.join(dice))

@bot.command(name='relaod', help='startet einmal den bot neu')
async def bot_reload(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    message = await ctx.send("Starte neu, gib mir 5 Sekunden")
    restart_bot()


@bot.command(name='create-voice', help='Erstellt einen Voice channel')
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def create_channel(ctx, channel_name="Default Channel"):
    guild = ctx.guild
    existing_channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=channel_name)
    if not existing_channel:
        print(f'Erstelle den Spach-channel "{channel_name}"')
        await guild.create_voice_channel(channel_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run(TOKEN)
```

it worked all, until i added the reload/restart function
after that nothing works anymore, the bot starts, and the on_ready() function is called, but in discord i cannot issue any command if you need the log file let me know

```
logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='discord.log', encoding = 'utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

    def restart_bot():
        python = sys.executable()
        os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
    @bot.command(name='relaod', help='startet einmal den bot neu')
    async def bot_reload(ctx):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        message = await ctx.send("Starte neu, gib mir 5 Sekunden")
        restart_bot()
    @bot.command(name='relaod', help='startet einmal den bot neu')
    async def bot_reload(ctx):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        message = await ctx.send("Starte neu, gib mir 5 Sekunden")
        restart_bot()
```

thats all the code i added before it stoped working

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code. Could you shorten it a bit to help us narrow down the error?

Comment: @knosmos like that?

Comment: try using `os.execv(sys.argv[0], sys.argv)` instead of `os.execl`?

Comment: still no commands work

Comment: Have you resolved the problem?

Comment: you have a duplicate function (async def bot_reload(ctx))

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand much of the code, but if you aren't trying already, execute the code in a new window and then close the current window. This can be done via:

```py
import os
os.system('YourBot.py')
os.exit()
```

I am not 100% sure that this will work but you can give it a throw.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30358013)

Comment: @webknjaz I was only doing my best to help someone and I gave an answer that I thought would work. I am sorry if it doesn't work but I can only do so much as of helping someone. And the asker did not ask for clarification yet,

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible solutions

Please excuse me, I have not tested your code yet but here is what I think may have gone wrong

##### 1. Permission check for `discord.log`

```
logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='discord.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

##### 2. Providing token while restart

The `restart_bot` function is restarting the Python interpreter and re-executing the script. However, the new process doesn't have access to the Discord bot token (TOKEN) and other environment variables, causing the bot to fail. (Not sure about this but you can try - )

```
def restart_bot():
    python = sys.executable
    os.environ['DISCORD_TOKEN'] = TOKEN  # Store the Discord token in the environment variable
    os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)
```